# Automatically mapping columns with EZApi with OLEDBSource

Tags: c#, ssis, ezapi

Using EZApi, an EzOleDbSource object is created, and assigned the Table property. 
Another task is added (EzDerivedColumn) and attached to the EzOleDbSource object. 
When I open the package, I need to click on the OLEDB source to get the column output to the input of the derived task.

Is there a way to programatically set the input and output mappings using EzApi? Note: I am using LinkAllInputsToOutputs();

Code:

```
        EzSqlOleDbCM RefConn = new EzSqlOleDbCM(package, dataVault_ConMgr);
        EzOleDbSource ezOleDbSource_SatFromStaging = new EzOleDbSource(satelliteDft);
        ezOleDbSource_SatFromStaging.Table = formatSQLTableName(settings.bd_datavault_schema_staging, stgTable);
        ezOleDbSource_SatFromStaging.Name = settings.ssis_prefix_dataflow_oledb_source + stgTable;
```

ezOleDbSource_SatFromStaging.LinkAllInputsToOutputs();

```
        EzDerivedColumn ezDerivedColumn = new EzDerivedColumn(satelliteDft);
        ezDerivedColumn.LinkAllInputsToOutputs(); 
        ezDerivedColumn.AttachTo(ezOleDbSource_SatFromStaging);
        ezDerivedColumn.Name = settings.ssis_prefix_task_derived + stgTable;
```

Comment: If you swap the order of AttachTo and the LinkAllInputsToOutputs, does it make any difference?

Comment: It does not make any difference if they are swapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the best code but this is working for me. It generates a package with a data flow that has an OLE DB Source, a Derived Column that just does a substring and writes to a table.

I get some warnings and information messages but I think that's due to not enough time working with derived columns programmatically.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a package with a data flow that pulls from table src_dWolf
    /// <example>
    /// CREATE TABLE dbo.src_dWolf
    /// (
    ///     le_key int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    /// ,   le_value varchar(50) NOT NULL  
    /// );
    ///
    /// CREATE TABLE dbo.dst_dWolf
    /// (
    ///     le_key int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    /// ,   le_value varchar(50) NOT NULL  
    /// ,   le_newValue varchar(20) NOT NULL
    /// );
    /// 
    /// INSERT INTO dbo.src_dWolf
    /// (
    ///     le_key
    /// ,   le_value
    /// )
    /// VALUES
    /// (
    ///     10
    /// ,   'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU'
    /// );
    /// </example>
    /// </summary>
    public static void Demo()
    {
        string dataVault_ConMgr = @"Data Source=localhost\DEV2012;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=TypeMoreClickLess;";
        EzPackage package = new EzPackage();
        string stgTable = "src_dWolf";
        string bd_datavault_schema_staging = "dbo";
        string ssis_prefix_dataflow_oledb_source = "SRC ";
        string ssis_prefix_task_derived = "DST ";

        EzDataFlow satelliteDft = new EzDataFlow(package);
        satelliteDft.Name = "DFT demo";

        EzSqlOleDbCM RefConn = new EzSqlOleDbCM(package, dataVault_ConMgr);
        RefConn.Name = "TMCL";
        RefConn.ConnectionString = dataVault_ConMgr;

        EzOleDbSource ezOleDbSource_SatFromStaging = new EzOleDbSource(satelliteDft);
        ezOleDbSource_SatFromStaging.Table = String.Format("[{0}].[{1}]", bd_datavault_schema_staging, stgTable);
        ezOleDbSource_SatFromStaging.Name = ssis_prefix_dataflow_oledb_source + stgTable;
        ezOleDbSource_SatFromStaging.Connection = RefConn;

        EzDerivedColumn ezDerivedColumn = new EzDerivedColumn(satelliteDft);
        ezDerivedColumn.Name = ssis_prefix_task_derived + stgTable;

        ezDerivedColumn.InsertOutputColumn("le_newValue");
        ezDerivedColumn.SetOutputColumnDataTypeProperties("le_newValue", Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.DataType.DT_STR, 20, 0, 0, 1252);
        // http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/137af5f4-3d35-45c2-9a3f-2127dc98fb6c/ezapi-how-to-working-with-ezderivedcolumn?forum=sqlintegrationservices
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSOutputColumn100 derCol = ezDerivedColumn.OutputCol("le_newValue");
        derCol.CustomPropertyCollection["FriendlyExpression"].Value = "SUBSTRING([le_value], 1, 20 )";
        derCol.CustomPropertyCollection["Expression"].Value = "SUBSTRING([le_value], 1, 20 )";

        ezDerivedColumn.AttachTo(ezOleDbSource_SatFromStaging);

        EzOleDbDestination ezOleDbDestination = new EzOleDbDestination(satelliteDft);
        ezOleDbDestination.Name = "DST dst_dWolf";
        ezOleDbDestination.Table = "[dbo].[dst_dWolf]";
        ezOleDbDestination.Connection = RefConn;
        ezOleDbDestination.FastLoadKeepIdentity = true;
        ezOleDbDestination.FastLoadKeepNulls = true;
        ezOleDbDestination.FastLoadOptions = "TABLOCK,CHECK_CONSTRAINTS";
        ezOleDbDestination.AccessMode = AccessMode.AM_OPENROWSET_FASTLOAD;
        ezOleDbDestination.AttachTo(ezDerivedColumn);
        ezOleDbDestination.LinkAllInputsToOutputs();


        package.SaveToFile(@"C:\sandbox\TypeMoreClickLess\EzAPIDemo\dwolf.dtsx");
    }
```

Comment: do you know if there is a way to automatically add all output columns without having to hard code them?

Comment: Could you restate the question? I don't understand the "automatically add output columns"

Comment: I ended up using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo to create columns to the derived task on the fly. The original bug ended up bieng ezOleDbSource_SatFromStaging.Connection = RefConn, which was not set after declaring EzOleDBSource.