# SSIS: Adding multiple Derived Columns without using the gui?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have about 500 fixed width columns in a flat file that I want to apply the same logic to to replace an empty column with null before it goes into the database.

I know the command to replace the empty string with null but I really don't want to have to use the gui to input that command for every column.

So is there a tool out there that can do this all on the back end?

Comment: Couldnt you script it using .net?

Comment: I can but my googlefu is not working well today and I am not getting how to open the existing package, edit it, and then save it back. Suggestions?

Comment: in .net you can use a `StreamReader` to open the file. Find the data you want to update and then use `StreamWriter` to make the update. Not very sexy but it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My googlefu worked a little better after lunch.

I as able to modify about the 5th comment down on   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/222e70f5-0a21-4bb8-a3fc-3f365d9c701f/ssis-custom-component-derivedcolumn-programmatically-problems?forum=sqlintegrationservices to work for my needs.

My c# code will now loop through all the input columns from a "Flat File Source" object and add a derived column for each.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at something like the EzAPI to create your data flow. This this answer, I have an example of how one creates a EzDerivedColumn and sets the formula within it.

[Automatically mapping columns with EZApi with OLEDBSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529606/automatically-mapping-columns-with-ezapi-with-oledbsource/19599624#19599624)

If you can install third party components, I've seen a number of implementations of a Trim-To-Null functionality on codeplex.com

BIML might be an option to generate your package as well. I'd need to play with that to figure the syntax though.

Comment: I'm using TRIM(ColumnName)=="" ? (DT_STR, 4, 1252)NULL(DT_STR, 4, 1252) : ColumnName but I don't really want to have to go through the gui for each column and would love to be able to open the dtsx somehow and loop through all my columns and add that. The xml for each derived column is 2 lines long with some auto generated ids so I"m not thinking that would work to edit that.

Comment: So basically. 
How do I open the SSIS package in say visual studio.
Loop through all the columns in the Flat File.
Add the above command.
Save the SSIS package.

Comment: Right and you wouldn't want to try and edit the XML by hand. That's why I was pointing you at the SSIS .NET APIs. You'll need to code something to make that happen.