# Warning messages with EZAPI EzDerivedColumn and input columns

Tags: ssis, ezapi

When adding a derived column to a data flow with ezAPI, I get the following warnings

> "Add stuff here.Inputs[Derived Column Input].Columns[ad_zip]" on "Add
>   stuff here" has usage type READONLY, but is not referenced by an
>   expression. Remove the column from the list of available input
>   columns, or reference it in an expression.

I've tried to delete the input columns, but either the method is not working or I'm doing it wrong:

```
foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSInputColumn100 col in derFull.Meta.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(col.Name);
    derFull.DeleteInputColumn(col.Name);
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate for my question in the same area.  It was never answered and I never found a way around it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023857/receiving-warning-messages-with-ezapi-ezderivedcolumn-and-input-columns

Comment: I know. I tried to wake the thread in your post, but it got deleted by the an admin. Currently I have to go over the packages and fix this manually. Not very satisfying....

Comment: I leave it with the warnings.  These packages are constantly regenerated so it doesn't make sense for us.  They still work - it's just annoying to see the warning in the designer - which we never use anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following piece of code that fixes the problem.

I got it from a guy called Daniel Otykier. So he is propably the one that should be credited for it... Unlesss he got it from someone else :-)

```cs
static public void RemoveUnusedInputColumns(this EzDerivedColumn component)

    {
        var usedLineageIds = new HashSet<int>();

        // Parse all expressions used in new output columns, to determine which input lineage ID's are being used:
        foreach (IDTSOutputColumn100 column in component.GetOutputColumns())
        {
            AddLineageIdsFromExpression(column.CustomPropertyCollection, usedLineageIds);
        }

        // Parse all expressions in replaced input columns, to determine which input lineage ID's are being used:
        foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 column in component.GetInputColumns())
        {
            AddLineageIdsFromExpression(column.CustomPropertyCollection, usedLineageIds);
        }

        var inputColumns = component.GetInputColumns();

        // Remove all input columns not used in any expressions:
        for (var i = inputColumns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (!usedLineageIds.Contains(inputColumns[i].LineageID))
            {
                inputColumns.RemoveObjectByIndex(i);
            }
        }
    }


    static private void AddLineageIdsFromExpression(IDTSCustomPropertyCollection100 columnProperties, ICollection<int> lineageIds)
    {
        int lineageId = 1;

        var expressionProperty = columnProperties.Cast<IDTSCustomProperty100>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Expression");
        if (expressionProperty != null)
        {
            // Input columns used in expressions are always referenced as "#xxx" where xxx is the integer lineage ID.
            var expression = expressionProperty.Value.ToString();
            var expressionTokens = expression.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', '(', ')' });

            foreach (var c in expressionTokens.Where(t => t.Length > 1 && t.StartsWith("#") && int.TryParse(t.Substring(1), out lineageId)))
            {
                if (!lineageIds.Contains(lineageId)) lineageIds.Add(lineageId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is in the method AddLineageId'sFromExpression (missing from your example).

Comment: Sorry .. My bad. I have added it :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Simple but not 100% Guaranteed Method

Call ReinitializeMetaData on the base component that EzApi is extending:

```
dc.Comp.ReinitializeMetaData();
```

This doesn't always respect some of the customizations and logic checks that EzAPI has, so test it carefully. For most vanilla components, though, this should work fine.

### 100% Guaranteed Method But Requires A Strategy For Identifying Columns To Ignore

You can set the UsageType property of those VirtualInputColumns to the enumerated value DTSUsageType.UT_IGNORED using EzApi's SetUsageType wrapper method.

But! You have to do this **after** you're done modifying any of the other metadata of your component (attaching other components, adding new input or output columns, etc.) since each of these triggers the `ReinitializeMetaData` method on the component, which automatically sets (or resets) all UT_IGNORED `VirtualInputColumn`'s `UsageType` to `UT_READONLY`.

So some sample code:

```
// define EzSourceComponent with SourceColumnToIgnore output column, SomeConnection for destination

EzDerivedColumn dc = new EzDerivedColumn(this);
dc.AttachTo(EzSourceComponent);
dc.Name = "Errors, Go Away";

dc.InsertOutputColumn("NewDerivedColumn");
dc.Expression["NewDerivedColumn"] = "I was inserted!";            

// Right here, UsageType is UT_READONLY
Console.WriteLine(dc.VirtualInputCol("SourceColumnToIgnore").UsageType.ToString());

EzOleDbDestination d = new EzOleDbDestination(f);
d.Name = "Destination";
d.Connection = SomeConnection;
d.Table = "dbo.DestinationTable";
d.AccessMode = AccessMode.AM_OPENROWSET_FASTLOAD;
d.AttachTo(dc);

// Now we can set usage type on columns to remove them from the available inputs.
// Note the false boolean at the end.
// That's required to not trigger ReinitializeMetadata for usage type changes.
dc.SetUsageType(0, "SourceColumnToIgnore", DTSUsageType.UT_IGNORED, false);

// Now UsageType is UT_IGNORED and if you saved the package and viewed it,
// you'll see this column has been removed from the available input columns
// ... and the warning for it has gone away!
Console.WriteLine(dc.VirtualInputCol("SourceColumnToIgnore").UsageType.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly your problem and found a way to solve it. The problem is that the EzDerivedColumn has not the PassThrough defined in it's class.

You just need to add this to the class:

```c#
    private PassThroughIndexer m_passThrough;
    public PassThroughIndexer PassThrough
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_passThrough == null)
                m_passThrough = new PassThroughIndexer(this);
            return m_passThrough;
        }
    }
```

And alter the `ReinitializeMetadataNoCast()` to this:

```c#
 public override void ReinitializeMetaDataNoCast()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Meta.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection.Count == 0)
            {
                base.ReinitializeMetaDataNoCast();
                LinkAllInputsToOutputs();
                return;
            }

            Dictionary<string, bool> cols = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 c in Meta.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection)
                cols.Add(c.Name, PassThrough[c.Name]);
            base.ReinitializeMetaDataNoCast();
            foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 c in Meta.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection)
            {
                if (cols.ContainsKey(c.Name))
                    SetUsageType(0, c.Name, cols[c.Name] ? DTSUsageType.UT_READONLY : DTSUsageType.UT_IGNORED, false);
                else
                    SetUsageType(0, c.Name, DTSUsageType.UT_IGNORED, false);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

That is the strategy used by other components. If you want to see all the code you can check my [EzApi2016@GitHub](https://github.com/fpvmorais/EzApi2016). I'm updating the original code from Microsoft to SQL Server 2016.